# Is it possible to use ReCaptcha v3 in android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, recaptcha, captcha

The question is simple and located in header. All themes about using ReCaptcha in android app that i found are using second version of it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.